# How to get req.body parameters in multer s3

Tags: node.js, multer-s3

```
var upload = multer({
storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'bucket',
    metadata: function(req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, {
            fieldName: file.fieldname
        });
    },
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
        console.log('req.body', req.params.id); //not getting
        console.log('req.body', req.body);
        //Not getting param here that passed in api 
        //Need to save file on s3 at specific location i.e /foldername/filename
        //But the folder name not getting from API
        cb(null, file.originalname)
    }
})  }).array('userFile', 1);
```

Above is multer s3 code

```
app.post('/saveData', function(req, res, next) {
upload(req, res, function(err) {
    console.log('err' + err);
    var status = '';
    var result = '';
    var link = '';
    if (err) {
        status = false;
    } else {
        status = true;
    }
    result = {
        "status": status,
        "link": link
    }
});
res.send(result);   });
```

Above code where calling multer upload function. I am parsing data in API (from Angular2, set -Content-Type": "multipart/form-data) as formdata

```
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('userFile', file);
formData.append('fileName', fileName);
```

I require the `req.body` data from API like folder name and other, so I can put the file to specific place on S3. Need req.body data inside the key: `function(req, file, cb) {` of  multerS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in multer, but as said here you can reorder the parameters when sending.

https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/322#issuecomment-191642374

Answer (score -1):

Reading the source code of dropzone.js i've figured out that the problem is that S3 expects the file to be the last paramater of your formdata

If your file input is the last input of your form, you should also try to pass the reference of the form tag when you make a new instance of FormData()

```
<form
    id="myForm"
    className="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1"
>
```

so pass id like this: `new FormData(document.getElementById(myForm)`

then you should find in your key callback function req.body with the input values of your form